# Filter edges in Cytoscape Desktop

Tags: desktop-application, cytoscape

I'm trying to filter a network by some edge attribute keeping the nodes connected by edges that pass my filter.

So, in the Filter tab I select the column from Edge table and values range (I can keep the whole range with the same result). The message says "Selected 0 nodes and N edges". If I choose `select` I do see those edges, but if I select `show` the network is blank.

If I add a filter that all nodes pass together with the edge filter and choose `Match all (AND)`, I get "Selected 0 nodes and 0 edges". Nothing even get selected. If I choose `Match any (OR)` and `show` I can see the whole network with both selected and not-selected edges.

Is it a bug in Cytoscape, or am I doing something wrong?

Cytoscape for Windows v 3.8.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I can achieve what I want selecting the edges with filter, then creating a new network - in the top menu "New Network From Selection" button, "From Selected Nodes, Selected Edges". It keeps only edges that pass the filter and the connected nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, the "show" functionality is definitely broken for edges.  Works great for nodes, but not for edges.  Could you please use the "report a bug" to file a bug on that?

Thanks!

-- scooter

Comment: I did. Thanks for confirming.